# How to make VSCode recognize DefinitelyTyped global variable (grecaptcha) in Vuejs 3 TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, grecaptcha

I have a **Vue.js 3 TypeScript** project scaffolded with the command `npm init vue@latest`. Now I want to add **reCaptcha v2** to the project **from scratch** instead of installing support libraries like `vue3-recaptcha-v2` etc.

Then, instead of having to define the `grecaptcha` object myself, I used `npm i -D @types/grecaptcha` instead and in theory I should get the global variable `grecaptcha`, however, my VSCode cannot recognize this variable.

Screenshot:

[image: vscode cannot recognize grecaptcha global var]

`vite.config.js`

```js
import vueI18n from "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueI18n({ useVueI18nImportName: true })],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

`tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["element-plus/global", "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n/client"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.config.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.config.json`

```js
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "vitest.config.*", "cypress.config.*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

These files are initialized automatically by the command `npm init vue@latest`. Now what should I do to make VSCode understand global variables from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json`, add `@types/grecaptcha` to `compilerOptions.types[]`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@types/grecaptcha"]
  },
  ⋮
}
```

[image: screenshot]